# How to drop softDeletes from a table in a migration

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm adding the soft delete columns to my table in a migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table("users", function ($table) {
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

But, how can I remove these in my `down()` function, if I roll back the migration? Is there a built-in method to do this, or do I just manually delete the columns that get added?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

On your migration class use `dropSoftDeletes()`:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table("users", function ($table) {
        $table->dropSoftDeletes();
    });
}
```

This method can be found in `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php`:

```
public function dropSoftDeletes()
{
    $this->dropColumn('deleted_at');
}
```

Since Laravel 5.5, this information can be found [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#dropping-columns).

Comment: Thanks; is there any actual API documentation that you used to find this? I'm using the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2 which gives a good overview, but doesn't list every available method.

Comment: You better navigate through the core classes. The documentation is always lacking some sugar.

Comment: OMG, after dropSoftDeletes - we are going to have a mess of historical and actual records together...

Comment: Updating Laravel framework files is not a good move?!  What about updates, etc?

Comment: dropSoftDeletes() already exists in Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php (at least as of Laravel 8.12) so no updating of framework files is necessary.

Comment: They were always there, just not in the docs.
And I never suggested editing framework files, please don't do it @Jquestions